# Getting all clicked events in another page in Ionic Project

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-view

I have an Ionic project and I try to store an operation history. For example; I added some information through "food" form, "accommodation" form and "transportation" form. In each form I have a button related with them. I want to display all completed operations after clicking each button. For instance, when I add a food info by clicking food button, I should be directed to Completed Operations Page and see the completed operation like "You entered a food info". Then when I add a transportation info by clicking transportation button again  I should be directed to Completed Operations Page and see the all completed operation like "You entered a food info"
               "You entered a transportation info".

How can I do that ?[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK2rw.png)
[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOZl6.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I added screenshots of my program, when user click "CREATE ACCOMMODATION" button, program should be directed to completed operations page and give an information about what we did. To sum up, I want to create an operation history.

Answer (score 0):

You'll use $state.go() to navigate to the page once the operation is complete and you can display each information on the completed operations page using an Ionic list.

Store each transaction first in the local storage of the device and then use that to display the list.

Comment: `$state.go` AFTER process completed, what you need is to learn AngularJs and Javascript again, this isn't specific to Ionic. There are many great courses available online.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I am new in Ionic and I try to write a code shown below, when I click add button, program is directed to Operations page. But I could not understand the usage of local storage while searching on the net. Please could you give me an example usage of it?

Comment: controller('DirectCtrl', function($scope, $http, $log, $state) {

  $scope.onAccommodationButtonClick = function(){
  
   $state.go('app.completed');  
   
 }
})